# UITextView top of the text is shown half when pressed on new line, rest is clipped

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

Check out the gif below, as you see the textview is normal. When I press the return button the top text gets clipped, when I enter a letter or press return again its fixed. After that the next return also clips the text. There is also unnecessary space created at the bottom.

[image]

Here is the code I use under UITextViewDelegate:

```
func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {
    textView.h = textView.contentHeight
    contentTextContainer.h = textView.contentHeight + 20 //Unnecessary but..
}
```

Comment: it might sound a bit noobish but did you remove that 20 from `contentTextContainer.h = textView.contentHeight + 20`

Comment: i changed nothing. and somehow this got fixed with the xcode7 update

Comment: that sounds lame but awesome at the same time :p